# multiple records for one person in a form in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

For my internship I am making a database in Microsoft Access about employee's accidents at work. There is one table and one query in the database. For the form I want it to have one employee and all the previous and future dates of all the accidents they have had and the comments to show if they are repeating them. If this is possible how can it happen?

Comment: This question is *very* open-ended. You don't specify the database structure (fields) nor the format (Access, DBF, ...). Please update your post with this information and also include some sample entries.

Comment: how is it very opened ended im asking a specific thing to do on a form in access

Comment: Rereading it now I see that access = MS Access (not just "having access to something"). There is still no structure, or is this all part of the question? IMHO, there seems to be no effort from your end, just: "Could you please code all the queries and make this interface for me" type of question. Again, that's only my opinion...

Comment: there is structure to my question that im asking and as far as effort this is what i would like the database im working on to do in the form

Comment: You'll need at least two tables: one table for the employee information (their name, employee number, and stuff like that) and another table for the accidents (employee number of the person who had the accident, when it happened, what happened, etc.). Then you could use a Form with a [subform](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-HA101872705.aspx) to display the information.

Comment: by doing that would I be able to see all the previous dates for that oe person? @Gord Thompson

Comment: Yes, the main form would display the Employee information (name, etc.), and its imbedded subform would display the Accident information (date, description, etc.) for the current employee. Take another look at the link in my previous comment, and just think "Accidents" wherever they mention "Orders".

Comment: If you plan on having others use this then it would be wise to make the tables linked.  One back-end database and then front-end forms.  Allows for more control and saves headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least two tables: one table for the employee information (their name, employee number, and stuff like that) and another table for the accidents (employee number of the person who had the accident, when it happened, what happened, etc.). Then you could use a Form with an imbedded subform to display the information.

Microsoft has provided detailed information on how to use a subform here:

[Create a form that contains a subform](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-HA101872705.aspx)